# Laravel Route error Redirect to loggin Page

Tags: php, json, api, laravel-5

everyone, I'm using Postman and when I try to get http://kemakon.com/api/user?id=1 it goes to the login page

My API Route

```
  Route::middleware('auth:api')->get('/user', function (Request $request) {
    return $request->user();
     });
```

Comment: You're using `auth` middleware. You aren't logged in that's why you're being re-directed.

Comment: even when i log in it go to home page

Comment: Have you set all 404 pages to just return to `/home`?

Comment: no, i did it  !!

Comment: Solved it by using api_token in database